# ModSecurity CSRF rule alert

Tags: apache, csrf, owasp, mod-security

I have installed Owasp ModSecurity, after that all pages on my application have this rule alert.

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. 
[file "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] 
[line "31"] 
[id "981143"] 
[msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."]
```

I also tried to create a blank php file just to check, same rule alert is shown.
From this point I assume that the problem is not code level any more.

Here is the source code for [modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf)

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! I have nearly exactly the same problem... I was just wondering if you've figured it out yet. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

It's checking your application to ensure that you're using CRSF tokens on all pages. A blank php file will fail this check because you have to code the token into the form.

CRSF tokens are used to validate a postback from a web form came from your form in the page and not from an attacker. There is more information on this on Wikipedia: [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Your options are:

1. Implement CRSF checking in your application and supply the token.
2. Stop modsecurity checking for this problem by removing the link to modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf from the activated_rules directory. This is /usr/local/apache/conf/crs/activated_rules by default