# Modsecurity CSRF alert when using $_GET

Tags: php, apache, csrf, mod-security

When a client visits my PHP site hosted on my personal server, and he is including a variable in the URL (Ex. `https://www.example.com/test.php?t=somevalue`), modsecurity is displaying an error message in the `error.log` file.

Specs:

```
Server OS:   Linux server 3.2.0-4-486 #1 Debian 3.2.57-3 i686
Apache:      version 2.2.22
PHP:         version 5.4.4-14+deb7u9
Modsecurity: version 2.8.0
```

Error message:

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] [line "31"] [id "981143"] [msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249483/modsecurity-csrf-rule-alert) SO question is similar to mine, except I'm only getting the error when the client's browser is adding a variable.

Modsecurity is configured with the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) `base_rules` and `optional_rules`. I do not use symlinks for these.

The only thing out-of-the-ordinary about my server configuration is that it uses a self-signed SSL certificate, but I don't believe this has anything to do with the problem.

The error displays no matter what the PHP file contains, and does not occur with HTML files.

What is causing this error, and how do I eliminate it?

*If it is the lack of a CSRF token, how would I add one?*

Comment: what do you have under /etc/modsecurity/rules/ ?

Comment: The OWASP `base_rules` and `optional_rules`. I'm adding that to my question...

Comment: what is the content of modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf

Comment: AW, I would recommend not to use csrf protection rule and to implement your own. because it has a limitation against ajax.
Limitations - this implementation does not currently work with AJAX

Comment: I have not changed its contents. This is the content: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf

Comment: Yeah... but I don't use Ajax. If I have to in the future, I can implement something else.

Comment: CSRF tokens should not apply to query strings, but with that rule they are. you really can't do anything about that unless you want to modify the content of that rule

Comment: Is there an example of that rule, modified so that I am able to use $_GET variables?

Comment: Sorry, but ***what is your question?*** The CSRF token is obviously missing *but expected* by your rules. Configure according to your needs, that means, you adopt suggested OWASP examples. There is no out-of-the-box here.

Comment: Which function is it in the CSRF protection file that causes this error. I am not experienced with modsecurity.

Comment: You do not need to be very experience to read the line number out of the error message: `[line "31"]`  - the file is also named. With that line and the given rule there in, consult the documentation of mod_security, also the OWASP project / docs that are about it (if any). I guess somebody has thought up something to insert the rule in there and you perhaps most benefit by learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious:

> What is causing this error, and how do I eliminate it?

The error is caused by said rule. You can eliminate it by either providing the CSRF token or by disabling that rule.

Comment: even while stating the obvious, a +1 is just needed. :)

Comment: The rule is using the `modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf` file to protect against CSRF attacks if I'm correct... So the problem with $_GET variables is something else...right?

Comment: Would eliminating line 31 like you said cause modsecurity to be worthless in CSRF protection?

Comment: @hakre How do I `provide the CSRF token`?

Comment: @HelpingHand: Via the *SESSION* collection, the *append* action in that *SecRule* moves it in (if I see the same code as you). See https://secure.jwall.org/blog/2009/01/08/1231374852674.html how to link session data from PHP (and other languages).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned this is your personal server I guess that it is not hosting a business critical application. Therefore I assume that you are not worried about Cross Site Request Forgery.

If this is true you can simply not include (pull in) the config file "modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf" in your Apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The rule  (id 981143 in modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf) is a chained rule. first it checks if the request has any **ARG**UMENTS (your t param in the get url) and then it checks if the request CSRF values matches.

Since sensitive data of my app is always passed in POST, I've changed the rule so it will consider only POST request

in the above file change:

SecRule &ARGS "@ge 1" "chain,phase:2,id:'981143'

to:

SecRule &ARGS_POST "@ge 1" "chain,phase:2,id:'981143'

Or recreate as a custom rule to avoid loosing these changes of update.